# Asp.Net MVC 4 ModelState.IsValid return False

Tags: vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an Asp.Net MVC 4 application, I have this two model classes:

CompanyModel:

```
Public Class CompanyModel

    <Key()>
    Public Overridable Property CompanyID As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Enter a company name.")>
    <Display(Name:="Company")>
    <StringLength(80, ErrorMessage:="The {0} must have {2} characters.", MinimumLength:=2)>
    Public Overridable Property Name As String

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="Enter the DB ID.")>
    <Display(Name:="DB ID")>
    Public Overridable Property DBID As Integer

End Class
```

PersonModel:

```
Public Class PersonModel

    <Key()>
    Public Overridable Property PersonID As Integer

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="Enter the name.")>
    <Display(Name:="Name")>
    Public Overridable Property Name As String

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="Enter the pass")>
    <DataType(DataType.Password)>
    <Display(Name:="Password")>
    Public Overridable Property Password As String

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="Enter the mail")>
    <Display(Name:="E-mail")>
    Public Overridable Property Email As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Enter the company")>
    <Display(Name:="Company")>
    Public Overridable Property BcoID As CompanyModel

End Class
```

PersonController:

```
'
' POST: /Person/Create

<HttpPost()> _
Function Create(ByVal model As PersonModel) As ActionResult
    Try
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            personDAO.Save(model)
        End If

        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    Catch
        Return View()
    End Try
End Function
```

I have this code at the Views/Person/Create:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BcoID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.CompanyID, New SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "CompanyID", "Name"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BcoID)
</div>
```

When I'm creating new Person, at the PersonController when I try to save I get ModelState.Isvalid = False, the message is "Enter a company name." I don't know why it happens.

Anybody can help me?

**EDIT**

If I change my property from model.BcoID.CompanyID to model.BcoID.Name and I use an EditorFor, instead of using DropDownListFor. The ModelState.IsValid is True, but I need a DropDownList, so I put a DropDownList and now I have an validation massage ("The Company must have 2 characters.") at my View.

Here is what I have now:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name, New SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "CompanyID", "Name"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a company name property in your view because this property is required in your model:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)
</div>
```

Also the Label and ValidationMessage helpers are attached to the wrong property for your CompanyID property. It should be like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.CompanyID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.CompanyID, New SelectList(ViewBag.Company, "CompanyID", "Name"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.CompanyID)
</div>
```

Notice how the Label and the ValidationMessage are now correctly associated to the DropDownList.

Comment: You seem to be using some `Nome` property that I cannot see in your model. In your model there's a `Name` property.

Comment: Sorry, now I translate the properties.

Comment: Did you put an `@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.BcoID.Name)` inside your view as shown in my answer?

Comment: But you already have a DropDownList which is bound to the `CompanyID` property. This is the only information which is sent to the server when you submit your form. That's how the `<select>` element in HTML works. It will never send the name. So you will have to remove the Required attribute from your Name property and use the  `CompanyID` property (which should be Required) in order to retrieve the corresponding company name from your data store.